# Adobe Flash Pro CS6 movie looping after adding code to actionpanel

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

i have got a problem and cannot figure out. Everything is fine when i test the scene, i have added stop(); to my movie clip timeline and everything is fine until no code is added to the main stage. As soon as i start adding code to the stage, it starts looping? Because of this i'm stuck with a problem and cannot even develop further, because even mouse click events wont work of that looping... The code i am trying to add is just a simple move layer off stage after click on play button:

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;





introScreen.play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickAway);
    function clickAway(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        moveScreenOff(introScreen);
    }

    function moveScreenOff(screen:MovieClip):void
    {
        //Move the screen off...
        var introTween = new Tween(screen,"x",Strong.easeInOut,screen.x,(screen.width)*-1,1,true);
        //When the motion has finished...
        introTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, tweenFinish);
        function tweenFinish(e:TweenEvent):void
        {
            trace("tweenFinish");
            //Establish the game state...
            gameState = STATE_INIT_GAME;
            trace(gameState);
            //Fire off the gameLoop function at the frame rate of the movie...
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);
        }
    }
```

Comment: well the position IS a trainee and they gave me a task to create a basic flash app for android. What do you mean question has no info?  There is no code since i came up with this problem prior to starting writing it up so... There is the link to the flash, i would really appreciate if someone can take a look and try to add any code, i was adding mouse event on click to bounce off the intro screen and it won't work ,instead it makes movie loop. http://www.filedropper.com/veinsv2

Comment: `As soon as i start adding code to the stage, it starts looping?` -> Please show what code you have tried yourself adding. Otherwise, this question will be closed in no time as it has not shown much own effort so far, unfortunately.

Comment: Please edit it into the question. Use the `{}` code button to indent it.

Comment: i have added the code to the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your animations are looping continuously is because you have errors in your code.

```
Access of undefined property gameState.
Access of undefined property STATE_INIT_GAME.
Access of undefined property gameState.
Access of undefined property gameLoop.
```

You are trying to reference members that haven't been created yet or don't exist. Your main timeline starts at frame 1 with the code you referenced trying to access those variables and the `gameLoop` method. You need to setup the variables in the first frame to allow them to be referenced. i.e. under your import statements:

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

var gameState:String;
const STATE_INIT_GAME:String = "GAME_INIT";
```

then you need to add the `gameLoop` function:

```
function gameLoop(e:Event):void {
    trace('game loop running');
}
```

If you don't want those variables and that function setup there then you need to go to the frame using `gotoAndStop` or `gotoAndPlay` where those functions and variables can be declared and/or initialized, and stored into memory. Then they will be accessible.

Comment: That makes sense, the variables are yet to be created, but i did not realize it makes the movie loop. But aren't import statements supposed to work regardless as mouse click is calling a function for a tween to ease In Out off the stage but the button will not react to a click

Comment: You seem to be a little confused on how the import statements work. They only allow you to access and use the imported class, it doesn't solve any of your current errors. Currently your imports only allow you to use the `Tween`, `TweenEvent` constants, and the easing constants, nothing more. As far as your click listener not working (which is a separate issue), that is due to your instance naming issues in the `introScreen` display object. You don't have an instance name `play_btn` in the `introScreen` timeline on key frames: 9, 10, and 24.

Comment: yes i am a little confused since i never had any programming experience. But i am starting to pick things up now. Got everything running now, intro moves off, end game tracking calls for end screen etc. Now i will dig deep into tutorials how to code an actual game engine. Thank you mr. p1on , you helped me to move out of dead end and now it will be easier to navigate